# Objeto eliminado de tabla html vuelve aparecer cuando se filttra o se hace paginacion

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Buenas tares tengo un problema en una tabla html cuando elimino un dato de una tabla, cuando oprimo para eliminar algo de una tabla lo hago de la siguiente manera `$('#trdato').remove();` si lo quita del todo cuando ocurre el evento de eliminarlo y lo hago de esta manera para no tener que refrescar la pagina las veces que se elimine algo el problema esta en cuando se pagina o se hace el filtro lo que se elimino vuelve aparecer y estoy con un dataTable de bootstrap.

js como lo elimino

```
 idobj = document.getElementById('option').value;
$('#labelmodalcarga').text('Eliminando el elemento');

                  
                   setTimeout(function () {
                       $('#trobjeto' + idobj).remove();
                       listarObjetosEvento(idevent, 'show');
                       modalcarga.modal('hide');
                   }, 500);
```

jsp

```
 <tbody >
<c:forEach var="obj" items="${listobjetos}">
 <tr id="trobjeto${obj.getIdobjeto()}">
  <td>${obj.getMarca()}</td>
   <td>${obj.getEstado()} </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
   </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Podemos ver algo más del codigo y/o de la tabla. Creo que me hago una ideade lo que pasa

Comment: @JuanManuelGaravitoFacundo en la edicion agregue como lo elimino y el tr que mando eliminar y pues de bootstrap no se cual sera el codigo que hace el filtro y el que pagina

Comment: Cuando refrescas la pagina vuelve a cargar tu codigo, debes tener guardado en alguna parte que el objeto ha sido eliminado para que al cargar la pagina o refrescar lo identifique y lo borre o simplemente no lo muestre.

Comment: @AngelReynaTorrejon si refresco la pagina me evito el problema que mecione ya que no lo traeria de la base de datos por que no existe, pero si elimino algo de 1000 registros no deberia refrescar la pagina para mostrar 999 registros porque es mucha carga para el servidor por eso lo elimino con JQuery en el JS y de hay obiamente por post digo al controlador que valla al modelo y ejecute el sql para que lo elimine de la db, el problema esta en el frontend

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar la función donde eliminas, para ver cómo recibes el parámetro y el proceso completo de manipulación del DOM, no es necesaria la petición AJAX porque dices que esa parte funciona correctamente.